# How disable betterForm javascript

Tags: exist-db, xforms-betterform

I use exist-db with betterFORM to change xforms to HTML but betterFORM made a lot of javascript that I don't need it. Please help me to disable generate javascript in betterFORM.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding i think. The script *is* needed for betterFORM to work as all interaction is based upon AJAX requests happening under the hood. Therefore the script cannot be disabled.

Comment: I know, Only I want to use part of betterFORM that change xforms to xhtml form and I don't want to use its all services. I want only it change my xform fields to xhtml fields without any scripts.

Comment: sorry, missed your message - if it's still of interest: patch the xhtml.xsl, find the places where the scripts are imported (e.g. addDojoImport) and remove them. You can also overwrite the stylesheet with xsl:import.